# CGAffineTransform affects the corner radius of my UIView

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I'm applying a CGAffineTransform animation to a UIView with the following code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: delay, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    elementView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 0.4)
}) { (finished) in

}
```

The UIView scales correctly in the animation, but I also have the UIView's corner radius set to perfectly round the top and bottom of the view.

[image]

The problem is, when the scaling animation occurs, the corner radius of my UIView is "squished":

[image]

How can I ensure the corner radius remains perfectly rounded, while maintaining the scaling animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to just change the `frame` property of `elementView`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: delay, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    elementView.frame = CGRect(x: elementView.frame.origin.x, y: elementView.frame.origin.y, width: elementView.frame.size.width, height: elementView.frame.size.height * 0.4)
}) { (finished) in

}
```

or if you're using auto-layout:

```
heightContraint.constant = heightConstraint * 0.4
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: delay, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    elementView.layoutIfNeeded()
}) { (finished) in

}
```

Either way should keep your corner radius while shortening the view.

Comment: I have a circle of 12x12, which I grow 5 to each direction (center stays same) by setting the top/bottom/leading/trailing constraint's constant to `+= 5` but the corner radius definitely doesn't stay the same. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

The transformation scales down the corner radius too - I would expect it to behave that way. If you want to get the same result, just with the correct corner radius, you will have to use a different approach.

I myself would use a height constraint instead:

```
let heightConstraint = elementView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
heightConstraint.isActive = true
```

And then scale down the constant:

```
heightConstraint.constant = heightConstraint.constant * 0.4 // (or set to constant directly)
elementView.superView.setNeedsLayout()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: delay, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    elementView.superView.layoutIfNeeded()
}) { (finished) in

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: delay, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    elementView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 0.4)
    elementView.layer.cornerRadius /= 0.4 // <-- solution
}) { (finished) in

}
```

Playground version:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let w: CGFloat = 10
let h: CGFloat = 100
let radius = w/2
let elementView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: w, height: h))
elementView.backgroundColor = .red
elementView.layer.cornerRadius = radius

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    elementView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 0.4)
    elementView.layer.cornerRadius =/ 0.4 // <-- solution
}) { (finished) in

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = elementView
```

Comment: What is your `radius` var set to?

Comment: Same as original

Comment: Idk if this works entirely when scaleX and scaleY are different, but probably good enough.